# Blockchain Hyperledger Fabric dev env setup

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am very close to set up dev environment for hyperledger fabric and following this link 
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/master/docs/setup.md

When I run this command git clone -b v0.6 http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric
and run go build. I get following error:

> can't load package: package github.com/hyperledger/fabric: no
>   buildable Go source files in
>   /Users/test/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric

However when I run step 4 from the link, the build success.
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com//learn-chaincode/start

go build ./

Here build is not succeed only for http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric.

Any thoughts?

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

I think the manual is not precisely written here. You are not supposed to run `go build .` on the cloned fabric repository. The manual just states here, that if you are getting build errors **later**, the clone into your go sources did not work. I is not asking you to build the fabric repository. If your  `build` command is executed in step 4, everything should be set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting up the dev environment you want to build things for that after cloning the repo. This is done with make, thus e.g. `make all` to build and test all.

To build chaincode later on you use `go build` in the folder where you have the chaincode source file.